# Image added to UIPasteboard is not displaying PASTE option in TWITTER

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uikit, uipasteboard

I've searched for couple of post/questions asked over UIPasteboard which are posted on StackOverflow ,But i didnt find any solution to my problem so posting this question.

I want to paste copied image in a Twitters NewTwitt and in Facebook's comment but i am not getting paste option there even if there is image in the Pasteboard object. 
I am getting paste option in EMAIL, n it is also working fine.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
 //image is object of UIImage, which holds .png Image

 UIPasteboard *objPasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
 [objPasteboard setData:imageData forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

[image: Here in twitter i am not getting PASTE option, even if my UIPasteboard object have image.]

Do I need to implement anything more to paste it in Twitter and facebook. I am postimg the images Screen Shots for reference.

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant paste an `UIImage` to `UITextView` and where you are pasting this is an `UITextView`. It supports `NSString` not `UIImage`.
You can paste it in `SMS`. Which icons or symbols you see in `UITextView` they're `Unicode` characters not an `UIImage` both are different.

Comment: Thanks Vakul, I wann ask one more thing that, can we create our own emoji's. ie. by converting png images or using any other method.

Comment: You will have to concern with [http://unicode.org/](http://unicode.org/) team ...